# Custom ttf fonts are not showing properly in TextView on Android 4.4 KitKat

Tags: android, types, fonts, textview, android-fonts

I have some text which has some bolded parts. Until KitKat this strategy ([as mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)) worked perfectly well

My strings resources file:

```
<string name="multi_style_text">NON-BOLD TEXT \n<b>BOLD</b></string>
```

My application code in fragment:

```
txtView.setTypeface(FontUtils.getOstrichRegular(this.getActivity()));
...
public static Typeface getOstrichRegular(Context context) {
   return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                                "fonts/ostrich_regular.ttf");
}
```

Currently (in KitKat), the bolded part is not shown in the custom font, the non-bolded part is shown in the custom font. In previous versions of Android, all of the text was shown in the custom font.

What gives?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So, after being frustrated by this bug, I searched around and found a solution to the problem.
In my current project we use calibri.ttf font. that was working fine up to 4.4. Once i got the update to my nexus 4, All the TextViews with Calibri font were showing "ff" instead of the entire text.

THE FIX - get an .otf (open type font) version of your font, and put in the project, works like a charm. Too bad google didn't inform the developers on this and there's very little documentation on the matter.

Comment: What do ya know. I added an .otf version and it started working. Rock on Israel T, Boo Google!

Comment: @Israel Tabadi : Getting same issue and solved it with .otf format. Thank you Very Much.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is a [bug in KitKat and has been fixed in an internal tree](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61771).

Answer (score 0):

Put your custom font in android assets under folder name "font" or whatever you want

Try this

```
myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
            "fonts/<<your font>>.ttf");
```

in `onCreate()` then

```
[use youcontroll].setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

Best of Luck...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by converting my file.ttf to file.otf

remplace :

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/ostrich_regular.ttf");
yourTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

by :

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/ostrich_regular.otf");
yourTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

FYI : the .otf format work for all android version (not only on kitkat)

Answer (score 0):

After many hours searching for roboto.otf (2014 year) I understood that it was a mistake. Simply download a normal ttf font from https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto-2014 and copy to assets folder, then use setTypeface.
Also you may convert it to otf with any web-site.