# in 4.4 kitkat .string not show in proper text style?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

i am working on android arabic app.i got Arabic string from sqlite DB. my app show proper arabic text style in android 4.2 version. but when i run this app in android 4.4 kitkat the text of arabic string change.the text style not proper which i want.
what is this any body give me some idea about this.
 main class is...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//Variables.....
TextView arabicTV,urduTV;
TableLayout tablelayout;
TableRow tableRow;
Context context = this;;
Typeface arabicFont, urduFont;
int width, height, rowwidth, colwidth,fontsize;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tablelayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
    arabicFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Al Qalam Quran Publisher.ttf");
    urduFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf");


        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        Cursor c =db.getAllAyyat();
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String ayyat = c.getString(0);
                String urdu = c.getString(1);

                System.out.println(ayyat);
                System.out.println(urdu);
                tableRow = new TableRow(this);
                TableRow.LayoutParams rlp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(rowwidth, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                tableRow.setLayoutParams(rlp);
                tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                TableRow.LayoutParams ulp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(colwidth, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                urduTV = new TextView(this);
                urduTV.setLayoutParams(ulp);
                urduTV.setText(urdu);
                urduTV.setTypeface(urduFont);
                urduTV.setPadding(1, 2, 1, 2);
                urduTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                urduTV.setTextSize(35);
                tableRow.addView(urduTV);

                TableRow.LayoutParams alp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(230, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                alp.setMargins(0, 3, 0, 4);
                arabicTV = new TextView(this);
                arabicTV.setLayoutParams(alp);
                arabicTV.setText(ayyat);
                arabicTV.setTypeface(arabicFont);
                arabicTV.setPadding(1, 2, 1, 2);
                arabicTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                arabicTV.setTextSize(35);
                tableRow.addView(arabicTV);


                tablelayout.addView(tableRow);
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
    } 


}
```

Comment: what code you are using to display strings?

Comment: @naveenprince now see my code

Comment: i hear that *.ttf have problems in kitkat

Answer (score 1):

i hear that *.ttf have problems in kitkat, use an *.otf Typeface [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107072/multiple-styles-for-same-textview-not-working-with-android-kitkat-4-4). I think there are online converters for this